# Do I need linear output in a neural netework?

Tags: r, neural-networks, keras

I tried to solve the XOR problem with 2 almost identical neural networks, see `R Keras` code below. What differs between the NN is that in the second network, I have added a **linear** output node, which if I understood the NN-litterature correctly, is how feedforward NN usually are designed (eventually more than one output node depending on problem).

By intuition, I would guess that the optimization of these NN should almost be equally hard, but running these codes gives notably different results.

#### Result after 50 epochs from first network, no linear out

[image: Result after 50 epochs from first network, no linear out]

#### Result after 50 epochs from first network + linear out

[image: Result after 50 epochs from first network + linear out]

As we can see, the network with the extra linear output has a much harder time to converge. I ran the code multiple times and got similar results. If I run the second code with more epochs, it eventually do converge (but not as smooth as the first code)

#### Result after 200 epochs from first network + linear out

[image: Result after 200 epochs from first network + linear out]

If I understand my code correctly, the two networks looks like this:

$$\text{2 Inputs} \rightarrow \textbf{W}^{1} \rightarrow \text{10 ReLU nodes} \rightarrow \textbf{W}^{2} \rightarrow \text{1 Sigmoid node} \rightarrow \text{1 Output}$$
and
$$\text{2 Inputs} \rightarrow \textbf{W}^{1} \rightarrow \text{10 ReLU nodes} \rightarrow \textbf{W}^{2} \rightarrow \text{1 Sigmoid node} \rightarrow \textbf{W}^{3} \rightarrow \text{1 Linear node} \rightarrow \text{Output}$$

where weights are $\textbf{W}^{1}: 2\times10$, $\textbf{W}^{2}: 10\times1$, $\textbf{W}^{3}: 1\times1$. Thats is, by adding one extra linear output node the convergence has changes drastically.

So to my questions. **Is this standard behaviour?** I recently started to play around with NN so I don't know what to expect really. **Should I use this extra linear output**, or is the sigmoid enough? Eventually, **when should I use an extra linear output layer?**

#### Data

```
library(keras)
library(tidyverse)

XORdata = data.frame(output = c(0,1,1,0),
                     x1 = c(0,0,1,1),
                     x2 = c(0,1,0,1))

X = model.matrix(output ~ . -1, data = XORdata)
y = XORdata$output

ggplot(data = XORdata) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = x2, shape = as.factor(output)), size = 4) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Output", values=c(4, 16))
```

#### Neural network 1, sigmoid output, no linear output

```
myNN1 <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "relu", input_shape = ncol(x)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

myNN1 %>% compile(loss = "mse", 
                  optimizer = optimizer_sgd(learning_rate = 0.5),
                  metrics = list("mean_absolute_error"))

history1 <- myNN1 %>% fit(X, y, epochs = 50, batch_size = 1)
```

#### Neural network 1, sigmoid output + linear output

```
myNN2 <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = "relu", input_shape = ncol(x)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1)

myNN2 %>% compile(loss = "mse", 
                  optimizer = optimizer_sgd(learning_rate = 0.5),
                  metrics = list("mean_absolute_error"))

history2 <- myNN2 %>% fit(X, y, epochs = 50, batch_size = 1)
```

Comment: You seem to have used arbitrary, fixed learning rates. Have you tried turning the learning rates? There is no reason why the same learning rate should lead to the same convergence for different models, so there is not much to compare. In general, the linear layer at the end should not be useful and it is not a common practice. By the way, why you treat this as regression not a classification?

Comment: @Tim No I haven't changed the learning rate, I just chose something that seemed to work. When you say regression, you mean that I use mean squared error as loss function and not (for example) binary cross-entropy? I just used first option I recognized and it seemed to work. It's the first time I create a neural network and I got stuck with the idea if I should use a linear output or not. Thanks either way!

Comment: Learning rate has an effect on the results and convergence, so it is unlikely to have an arbitrary learning rate to work for any model, this is something you should tune using cross-validation. As for classification, yes I meant using cross-entropy, though squared error is perfectly fine metric for binary data, so this should not be that important, I was asking out of curiosity.